# Django related_table() with extra()

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm trying to use .extra() function with .related_table():

```
foo_objects = Foo.objects.all()
result = foo.extra(select={'is_ok':'IF(bar.is_ok,"Yes","No")'}).select_related('bar')
```

Foo and Bar are connected (Foo has bar_id) with models and everything, 
but I keep getting "Unknown column 'bar.is_ok' in 'field list'" when calling `result.values()`, 
Looking at the Query generated (the actual query produced, not foo.query), it doesn't 
seem to join the two, any ideas on how I do that ?

Comment: It's unclear as to what `foo` is in the `foo.extra(...)` line - is it supposed to be the `foo_objects` returned by the previous line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following query ought to work, but I can't really test it...

```
foo_objects = Foo.objects.select_related('bar').extra(select={'is_ok':'IF(bar.is_ok,"Yes","No")'})
```

It doesn't matter which order you do the `select_related()` and `extra()` in, as long as they're both on the same queryset.

---

**Update**

If you need it to work with a `ValuesQuerySet`, you can't use `select_related()`, so you have to do it slightly differently, by using additional parameters to the `extra()`...

```
foo_objects = Foo.objects.extra(tables=('bar',),
                                where=('foo.bar_id=bar.id',),
                                select={'is_ok':'IF(bar.is_ok,"Yes","No")'}).values()
```

...or if you don't need "Yes" and "No" back, you can just use...

```
foo_objects = Foo.objects.values('bar__is_ok')
```

...which will force the join.

See also Django ticket [#3358](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3358).

Comment: Actually, I just spotted the problem: values() alone doesn't create the join, but, if you simply pass the related fields as parameters: `values('bar__is_ok','otherfield')` , works great

Comment: Your solution does work, I did try the "tables" thing earlier on, but it created a lot of duplicates, tried to somehow manipulate the JOIN and saw there wasn't such option in .extra(), forgot the obvious possibilty of putting it in  WHERE.. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Asaf Yeah. I was just about to add in the `values('bar__is_ok')` approach, but got distracted by a phone call.